# Import package from unit test code

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

I like to keep my source code separate from test code. So, I have my project organized like this:

```
my_package/
   module1.py
   module2.py
tests/
  units/
    test_a.py
    test_b.py
  perf_tests.py
```

How should `test_a.py` import `my_package`?

Note: I've googled this (including SO) and am not satisfied with the answers:

- I don't want to use setup.py, because I want to run from development; this is for testing, after all
- I don't want to use symlinks or other hacks
- I've tried `sys.path.append('../')` and `sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('../'))`.  Both result in `ImportError: No module named my_package`. Perhaps something similar can be done with `PYTHONPATH` - What is the syntax?
- I do want to write a proper `import` statement which can find the correct files

Comment: What do you mean "how should I load the source code"?  Are you talking about importing something?  What module would you like to import from what module?  ...and what is a "proper include"?  ...there are no "includes" in python.

Comment: why not just use the PYTHONPATH environmental variable? thats what its for ...

Comment: @Gerrat - Thanks, rewrote question to address your points.

Comment: @Joran - I'm not sure how to do that: I've tried using sys.path and can't get it to work either

Comment: Are you in the tests/units directory? Try sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../..')).

Comment: ...or (assuming linux) do `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/my/stuff` at the beginning of your console session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to include a `__init__.py` file inside folder `my_package` in order to allow Python to recognize this folder as a valid module. You can create an empty `__init__.py` file just with one line `pass`, for example.

Then, you can do something like this in `test_a.py`:

```
import os
bkp = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(r'..\..')
import my_package
os.chdir(bkp)
```

Or use the other options with `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path.append()`.